# ATOM E3845 CPU Bay Trail, support for PTN3460 DP-LVDS Bridge?

Tags: intel-graphics, intel-atom

To connect a LVDS TFT-Display our mainboard uses a NXP PTN3460 DP-LVDS Bridge. On the kernel tree (Ubuntu 15.10) a driver module is availible but not selectable by kernel config. When can we expect the support for the PTN3460 Display Port - LVDS bridge?